# caroussel bootstrap upside down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I use carousel with bootstrap and some of my pictures are upside down. I search in the configuration of my pictures and I try  to upside down them before but no result. Do you know a class or a javascript function for this?
Thank you very much.

Markup

```
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block w-100 img-thumbnail rounded float-left img-fluid" style="background-color:#ffba00" src="image/p10.jpg" alt="Forth slide">
```

Comment: 1) Try save image to a .bmp, then back to whatever original format was. 2) resize the image. It could be due to the image size.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) !!! it worked with the first. i'm happy. Have a good day.

Comment: Good to know. I put it as an answer down below. :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comment.

1. Make sure that there is no *funky* image encoding. One way to ensure
   that is to save your image to a *loseless* format, such as .bmp, and then re-save it back to its original format.
2. Make sure that your image has the correct size.